# createAsyncThunks first promise is fulfilled, but subsequent promises are always rejected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I have a `saveTrip` function that is a redux async thunk. However, i am getting very weird behavior as only my first promise is resolved as "fulfilled" and every promise after that is "rejected"

```
export const saveTrip = createAsyncThunk(
    'trip/saveTrip',
    async (payload, thunkAPI) => {
        const trip = thunkAPI.getState().trip
        const result = await fetch(
            'http://localhost:5000/savetrip', {
            mode: 'cors',
            credentials: 'include',
            method: "post",
            body: JSON.stringify({ trip }),
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
        })
        const response = await result.json()
        return response
    }
)
```

Whats more unusual is that i stumbled upon a bandaid fix by implementing debounce like so :

```
export const saveTrip = createAsyncThunk(
    'trip/saveTrip',
    debounce(async (payload, thunkAPI) => {
        const trip = thunkAPI.getState().trip
        const result = await fetch(...)
        const response = await result.json()
        return response
    }, 5000)
)
```

Debounce doesnt actually "work" as i expect debounce to, but now, every promise is getting fulfilled with the expected data in the responses. Im pretty sure this is not a proper solution but I am very confused as to what's happening.

My goal is to just save my current `state` into my DB and i just call `saveTrip` whenever a reducer that changes my `state` is dispatched.

[image: The error i get from the rejection in actions]

Comment: What exactly is the error message on the rejected action? Take a look in the Redux DevTools.

Comment: Its a syntax error? i edited the post to include a screenshot. It seems that the id (string) that i am returning as the response is not happy that i am "parsing" a string? but im not sure why the first promise would fulfill at all

Comment: Try this: 
Change this line: const response = await result.json()
To: const response = await result.text()
and console.log the response to see what you get back from the first successful request
It will help you understand what kind of endpoint you're hitting and refactor accordingly.
Probably, the first request is resolved successfuly with an HTML error message from the backend, but since it's not a proper JSON structure it throws during the .json() parsing phase.

Comment: Also, the DevTools Network Tab is your friend is such cases.

Comment: @KostasMinaidis im not sure if im looking at the right place but i dont see any errors from the headers section in the network.. is that where the errors would normally be? but anyway thank you and phry. i needed to change my res.send to res.json to correctly return my string correctly.